# How to use ActionMenuView?

Tags: android, actionmenuview

Since SplitActionBar is no longer supported in Android 5.0, I am trying to use an ActionMenuView to achieve a SplitActionBar effect. But I could not find much information on how to use ActionMenuView.

I know I can add a ActionMenuView in the layout file, but I don't know how to add menu items. It doesn't seem like I could inflate them like I do with SplitActionBar.

Could you give some sample code on how to use ActonMenuView? Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure it out ? there is lack of resources on that.

Comment: @osayilgan I switched to other method for this part eventually. But you can take a look at George's answer. Please let me know if it works, if so I would  mark it as the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: I found another solution using resources from AppCompat Library Theme. With certain attributes, you can style the ActionView with background color and etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Getting `ActionMenuView` to display a whole screen's width of icons is a chore. Here is an example to do what you want. Make sure your `ActionMenuView` XML item is `wrap_content` for height and width, then `gravity` to the right. Surround it in a `LinearLayout` which takes the whole width and provides background color.

Use this code to initialize the `ActionMenuView` (obviously you will need to change the button callbacks)

```java
ActionMenuView actionMenuView = (ActionMenuView) findViewById(R.id.editBar);

final Context context = this;
MenuBuilder menuBuilder = new MenuBuilder(context);
menuBuilder.setCallback(new MenuBuilder.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder menuBuilder, MenuItem menuItem) {
        return onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMenuModeChange(MenuBuilder menuBuilder) {

    }
});

// setup a actionMenuPresenter which will use up as much space as it can, even with width=wrap_content
ActionMenuPresenter presenter = new ActionMenuPresenter(context);
presenter.setReserveOverflow(true);
presenter.setWidthLimit(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, true);
presenter.setItemLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

// open a menu xml into the menubuilder
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.editbar, menuBuilder);

// runs presenter.initformenu(mMenu) too, setting up presenter's mmenu ref...  this must be before setmenuview
menuBuilder.addMenuPresenter(presenter, this);

// runs menuview.initialize too, so menuview.mmenu = mpresenter.mmenu
actionMenuView.setPresenter(presenter);

presenter.updateMenuView(true);
```

For what it's worth, I had to read the support library source code for 8 hours to get this to work. The documentation is garbage.

Comment: This method will no longer work because ActionMenuPresenter is now private in the support library.

Answer (score 10):

It seems the API has changed in the meantime. Currently, the following code works:

```java
ActionMenuView actions = new ActionMenuView(activity);

MenuBuilder menuBuilder = (MenuBuilder) actions.getMenu();

menuBuilder.setCallback(new MenuBuilder.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder menuBuilder, MenuItem menuItem) {
        return onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMenuModeChange(MenuBuilder menuBuilder) {
    }
});

inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menuBuilder);
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but do you know how to set the number of visible items?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the v7 appCompat library make sure your activity extends from `ActionBarActivity` and that you use the support version of the `ActionMenuView`.

Likewise if you are not using the support library be sure to use the `ActionMenuView` outside the support library.

From there you can get the `ActionMenuView` from your layout and populate its menu using the following method:

`getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu_here, actionMenuView.getMenu())`

If you aren't in an activity where `getMenuInflater()` is accessible create your own `MenuInflater` or `SupportMenuInflater`.

Answer (score 0):

In `appcompat-v7:27.0.2`, the `ActionMenuView` requires a minimum width of `56dp`. Do not use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.

If your popup theme is being ignored, make sure you call `setPopupTheme(int)` before any call to `getMenu()` on `ActionMenuView`.

Answer (score 0):

### Inflate

you can use this code in your activity :

```
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.{your_menu_res_id}, {your_ActionMenuView_instance}.menu)
```

like this :

```
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.settings_menu, settings_menu.menu)
```

### Item Click Listener

then you can add item click listenter :

```
{your_ActionMenuView_instance}.setOnMenuItemClickListener()
```

like this :

```
settings_menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
        when (menuItem.itemId) {
            R.id.menu_settings_save -> {
                // your code

                return@setOnMenuItemClickListener true
            }
            else -> return@setOnMenuItemClickListener false
        }
    }
```