# How to have the title of a toolbar on top of the menu

Tags: android, xml, menu, toolbar

I'm trying to figure out how to have the title of a toolbar on top of the menu but I don't find anything online.

basically I want to have the same toolbar as google maps on that screenshot at the bottom:
[their app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMssJ.png)
but at the moment I only have this:
    [my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLr3y.png)

Here is how I add menu in my toolbar

```
    toolbar = this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.a_menu);
    toolbar.setTitle("Title");
```

Here is the XML for my toolbar

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="156dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:gravity="top|left"

    ></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use a custom title by adding a `TextView` within the `Toolbar`.
That actually won't solve the problem, but it will allow you to add your menu below this `TextView` by using custom layout within the `Toolbar`.

and to add the menu in certain place within the `Toolbar`, you can use `ActionMenuView`, and add the menu programmatically within `onCreateOptionsMenu()` activity callback, and handle menu clicks with `onOptionsItemSelected`

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActionMenuView mMenuView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Inflating ActionMenuView
        mMenuView = findViewById(R.id.menu_view);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Adding menu to the ActionMenuView
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.a_menu, mMenuView.getMenu());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // handle menu clicks
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**Your Toolbar**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="156dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:gravity="top">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="3 E Main Street" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView
            android:id="@+id/menu_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

**How it looks**

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it worked except that I had trouble intercepting clicks until I began experimenting with this underdocumented MenuBuilder API. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988346/how-to-use-actionmenuview