# Android - actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled issues

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity

In my activity which extends SherlockFragmentActivity I have action bar and have also set  actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) to come back to my previous activity. Everything works fine. But when i click on home button, the background color should be applied only to the app icon but it also applies to the "title" on action bar as shown in screen shot. I dont want this to happen. When i click on home button, only the app icon should be click able(background color should be applied only for app icon) and not the title. Any idea how can i do this?

[image]

my activity code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setTitle(some_string);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Android UI pattern is to include the title in the pressed state.
However, I think if you followed this link (describing how to add a custom view to the left of an actionbar) [How to align items in action bar to the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454102/how-to-align-items-in-action-bar-to-the-left) , and set the title to empty. The below code worked on my local device

```
ActionBar action=getActionBar();
action.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
action.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
TextView title =new TextView(getApplicationContext());
title.setText("Your Title here");
title.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
action.setCustomView(title);
```

Comment: thank you. It works, But i have also set text size and color with your answer like this : http://pastebin.com/CtMf0gSD . will I face any problems with this while running on different screen sizes.

Comment: Possibly, I would test with several screen sizes in the emulator. With your title and only two ActionBar items I don't think it will be an issue, but if you stack more in the buttons and text will overlap.

The main issue is that the title is now outside of the design flow (it's just part of the background), so it won't respond automatically.

Answer (score 17):

Don't forget this part, because that home button is also a MENU button.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This is called when the Home (Up) button is pressed in the action bar.
            // Create a simple intent that starts the hierarchical parent activity and
            // use NavUtils in the Support Package to ensure proper handling of Up.
            Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
                // This activity is not part of the application's task, so create a new task
                // with a synthesized back stack.
                TaskStackBuilder.from(this)
                        // If there are ancestor activities, they should be added here.
                        .addNextIntent(upIntent)
                        .startActivities();
                finish();
            } else {
                // This activity is part of the application's task, so simply
                // navigate up to the hierarchical parent activity.
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
            }
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Not working  here us my code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138629/action-bar-detect-back-button-click-in-fragment#29138683