# Action Bar detect back button click in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar-compat

I have a Fragment with action bar back button enabled in it.

Code :

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        actionBar = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

        return view;
    }
```

In the above code `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` enables the back button in the Action Bar but how can we detect the click on it ?

I have looked into many examples and tried the below but still not working :

In Fragment :

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Also the back button which is displayed in the fragment is of Black color i need that in White color or with custom color how can i change that as well ?

Comment: onOptionSelectde(MenuItem item) is even for menu item,and with actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) , It gives back facility automatically..Dont go through its click event....

Comment: @VidhiTrivedi When i click on that it does nothing , so what would be my next step to check what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: i m also facing same problem any one found sol for this ? unable to detect android.R.id.home event

Answer (score 8):

Better late than never, please try this>

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        //set setHasOptionsMenu on true here on CreateView method
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return view;
    }
```

and implement

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
            if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                if (getActivity() != null) {
                    getActivity().onBackPressed();
                }
                return true;
            };
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Fragment's onOptionsItemSelected is never called. It goes and calls the activity's method directly

Comment: You can have onOptionsItemSelected only in fragment, not in both activity and fragment. It fits my requirements. It's a nice approach as for me.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem, but then I put this code inside the activity and the back button worked from inside the fragment:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   finish(); //to finish current activity
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Anyone came across the this question could follow steps below;

Implement MenuProvider to your fragment class and use MenuHost to initialize your menu inside fragment, then use overrided methods.

```
class NumbersFragment : Fragment(), MenuProvider{

    private val args: NumbersFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_numbers, container, false)

        val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
        menuHost.addMenuProvider(this, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)

        val numberListView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.numbersListView)
        val adapter = NumbersAdapter()
        adapter.setNumberList(args.numberArguments)
        numberListView.adapter = adapter

        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        //Nothing
    }

    override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        this.findNavController().popBackStack()
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `requireActivity().onBackPressed()` instead of `this.findNavController().popBackStack()`

Answer (score -3):

```
View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
cView.findViewById(R.id.btn_id).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Do stuff here.
    }
});
actionBar.setCustomView(cView);
```