# Action bar Action Item location

Tags: android, location, android-actionbar, alignment

I'm currently creating an app where it would be useful for the user to have all the options in the actionbar.

This is the current situation:

[image]

As you can see, Item1 and Item2 are on the right but I'd like to have these on the left side.
Is this possible?

If it is **not** possible, how would I simulate what I want? 
An `ImageView` with `Buttons` functioning as the `ActionBar`?

Comment: That would be horribly confusing for the user... Like a car maker that would like to change the position of the seats, mirrors and driving wheel.. Please reconsider your needs, but yes, that might be possible with a custom layout

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454102/how-to-align-items-in-action-bar-to-the-left

Google is your friend :)

Comment: @Waza_Be Hmm you are kind of right, though it is for a drawing app. So the user could choose between pencil/eraser/line-tool etc etc. Would be quite useful if all these tools were at the top. I could make my own custom action-bar and place it at the left side I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but I wanted something on the left, something in the middle, and overflow on the right. I created a custom `layout` with three `ImageButtons` for the three elements. Then used an `<include>` tag to include this `layout` in my `Activities` xml files.

I also created a `BaseActivity` for my other `Activities` to `extend` and put the `menu` functionality in there like `OnMenuItemClickListener()` then I could just `override` them in my `Activities` if I needed different functionality for a certain `Activity` aside from what it did in the `BaseActivity`. I also used `PopupMenu` here (requires API >= 11).